# C Programming (Beginner help) relating to getchar() putchar()

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar, putchar

Im new to C programming and wanted to clear, what may seem to be, a silly doubt...

Code:

```
#define EOF 0
main()
{ 
    int c;

    c=getchar();
    while (c!= EOF) 
    {
        putchar (c); 
        c= getchar();
    }
}
```

this should just return the value I enter...but accordingly...shouldnt it terminate when I enter 0? If not...what exactly does the statement under 'while' signify?
Any help would be greatly appreciated guys :)

Comment: When you enter '0', it reads the ASCII character '0', not the numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getchar` function returns the ASCII value entered (48 for zero, or `'0'`), or a value called `EOF` in the header file `<stdio.h>` (normally -1).

So if you want to stop either on EOF (the proper EOF, not the one you defined) or if the user writes a zero, then this will work much better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF && c != '0')
    {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanku, i was gettin mixed up in the basics :)

Answer (score 2):

`EOF` means when you hit, for instance, `ctrl + d` in linux, it sends `EOF` signal, it's not necessarily a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`EOF`is certainly not `0` (nor is it `'0'`, the char literal equaling 48). It's not `char` at all. `stdio.h` (which you should be `#include`-ing!) defines it as `-1`. It indicates that whatever file you are reading has no more data in it. It's not a byte in the stream, rather the way that the io library indicates that it has finished.

The whole reason `getchar` needs to return an `int` is so that the end-of-file indicator cannot possibly be a valid byte in the file.

Other functions indicate that the EOF has been reached differently: `fgets()` returns `NULL`. `read()` which returns the number of bytes read returns 0, indicating that it could read nothing.

Comment: Thank you, but i guess with what i wanted...i shud have put as #define '0' instead of just 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a `0`, it's not actually a zero, just the [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/) `0`. It has a numerical value of 48, which can be verified by `printf("%d\n", '0');`, which prints 48. An `EOF` is an *actual* zero, that is, it's representation is essentially zero.